# GET request from Millennial Media Ad server

Tags: blackberry, get, advertisement-server

Hi am try to make a GET request from millennial media for ads to be display in my blackberry java app but I can't seems to get it to work. This is what I have

```
HttpConnection conn = null;             
InputStream in = null;             
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();             
String result = ""; 

String url ="http://ads.mydas.mobi/getAdapid=157899&auid=ddd25abbb993f79454b12827c803fbafab2ad89b&ua";                          try {                 
conn = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory().getConnection(url).getConnection(); conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);                 
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",              
"Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");                 
if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {                     
in = conn.openInputStream();                     
// parser.parse(in, handler);                  
buff.append(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in));                     
result = buff.toString();                 
} else {                     
result = "Error in connection" + conn.getResponseCode();
((SettingWaitScreen)screen).update(result);              
} catch (Exception ex) {                 
ex.printStackTrace();             
} finally {                 
try {                     
if (in != null) {                         
in.close();                     
}                     
conn.close();                 
} catch (IOException e) {                     
e.printStackTrace();                 
}             
}
```

I don't know if this is correct method any help with doing this ad request is highly appreciated. This is what I get from the website at http://docs.millennialmedia.com/S2S/ad-request.html

Comment: I think you need to review the specification you link to and make sure that you are supplying all the information that the API calls for, in the way it requires it.  As far as I can see, you are not.  And for next time, when you report a problem like this, can you please describe exactly how far through this process you get and what error codes or information you receive.  Finally, I suspect that you would get better support from them directly, here is the URL you need.  https://tools.mmedia.com/user/supportDevPortal

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are using incorrect base URL.

Please check with below URL 
http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd?apid=157899&auid=ddd25abbb993f79454b12827c803fbafab2ad89b

Above URL is also working in browser.